# How to navigate between WPF and WinForms

Tags: wpf, winforms

I'm new to visual basic and i'm currently trying - and at the moment I've done my entire program using WPF's because I wanted to easily switch through different pages which i've hosted in a single window. Well I've come to a halt because I'm creating a page currently where a customer can enter their information and add it a data base.

Now, I have little experience in coding in visual basic(self taught for 2-3 weeks) and I have no clue how I would go about adding a database, and adding to the data base using WPF's. I have seen some examples of people adding a database, and adding to a data base using Forms.

**I was curious if I am able to using WPF's(page) for most of my program, and then switch to a Form when I want to add the customer to a database, then switch back to a WPF(page)?**

Comment: Do u mean WinForm and WPF is a single project?

Comment: @RAM Yes. Is it possible to navigate between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can...

If your main project is `WPF` you need `WindowsFormsHost` and if your main project is `WinForm` you need `ElementHost`. For more information you can read [this tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/).

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a look!

Comment: I'm a little confused. Let me go through my program a little bit to help give a better understanding. 

I start off with a MainWindow which I have a page being hosted in. 
I want to go from Page > Page > Page > Form > Page basically. I want to know if inside that MainWindow I can host a Form, the same way I am hosting pages.

Comment: Johnny Boy, your information is not clear enough... Please create a new question and write several important parts of your codes in it (related to your question). Additionally you can insert an image of what you want in your question. Then i and others can help you more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416077/navigating-between-wpfs-and-winforms-in-the-same-application