# Navigating between WPF's and WinForms in the same application

Tags: wpf, winforms, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to visual basic and I am currently coding in visual studio 2015. I am teaching myself visual basic (roughly 2-3 weeks). I work for a boat dealership, and I'm attempting to create an application that we can use at a boat show where Customers can come up to a computer and basically pick out a boat they want with all the additional options (any fishing rod holders, different color haul, motor etc).

**So far:**

I am using visual basic and decided I wanted to use WPF's. I currently have my program start up on the default the main MainWindow. Inside that MainWindow is where I host all of my future 'pages'

> Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="1200" Source="ChooseYourAdventure.xaml" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">

From here I have the customer choose which boat they are interested in and they click a button which then switches them to a new 'page' being hosted in MainWindow still. On the new 'page' they choose the motor, and once again click a button and go to a new 'page' where they finally choose the trailer type they are interested in.

**This is where things get difficult for me**

After the trailer 'page' I want to be able to take in the customers information(First name, last name, etc...) and add it to a database. Since I am unfamiliar with visual basic and especially with WPF's I have no clue what the strategy here is. Everything I've googled thus far always shows how to add records to a database through the use of 'Forms'.

**What I had in mind was using WPF's for most of the application then switching to a 'Form' for when I needed to enter in the customers information for the database**

**My question is: Is it possible to navigate from a WPF 'page' into a 'Form'?**

Comment: There is no need to mix Windows Forms (old technology to create Windows applications) and WPF (new technology to create Windows Applications). For tutorials look on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264923.aspx and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCfvcBObX8k

Comment: Agree with @jessehouwing, there is absolutely no need for winforms. It is a useless deprecated technology that's not suitable for today's UI needs. Better learn proper WPF, XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: Do you want host WPF inside Winform and get back data from WPF part to Form to save it in DB?

Comment: Johnny if you you give me the answer of my above question and if the answer be _YES_ then i can help you.

Comment: @RAM I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your main project as a `WPF Application` and your other project as a `Windows Forms Application` and set its output type as `Class Library`.
Then in main project (`WPF Application`) add a reference to other project (`Windows Forms Application`).
Now you can use all of the forms and classes of other project in your main project. To do so, it is enough to instantiate a form of other project in and show it.

For example if `Windows Forms Application` contains a `Form1`, you can use this code in button click handler of your main project:

```
//Instead of NameSpace put the namespace of Form1
var f= new NameSpace.Form1();
f.Show();
```

***Further more***, if you want to use a `UseControl` created by windows forms in your wpf forms, you can use [`WindowsFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can for legacy reasons, but one shouldn't for other reasons.

Comment: The main thing i'm trying to do is just save customer information into a DB. I don't know the best route to do so. I can't find a clear way to save customer information to a DB through WPF means, and everything I've found online tells me to use Forms.

Comment: This can be done using both frameworks, but if you are familiar with `Windows Forms`, so I strongly recommend yo to use `Windows Forms` to achieve your goal. :)